# SVN with Eclipse: Commit doesnt work, instead "Skipped" message

Tags: eclipse, svn, skip, svnignore

I use Eclipse with SVN. Besides others I have a folder "application". This folder contains several other folders, among these "cache" and "logs". I added the svn:ignore property to "cache" and "logs". Now "application" has this star-Symbol, meaning that it contains uncommitted changes. But when I try to commit, I get this message

```
commit -m "svn:ignore" -N C:/Xampp/htdocs/application
    Sending        C:/Xampp/htdocs/application
    Skipped
```

How to solve?

Comment: Did you try to make an update first? I got this behaviour when I had outdated versions in the commit tree.

Answer (score 1):

Long shot here since you didn't post the contents of an *svn status* but I suggest that you take a peek at http://www.tecnotertulia.com/development/svn-skipped-pathtofile-is-misleading/96.

Comment: I dont understand your link! Why is Eclipse telling me "Skipped"? How to solve it?

Comment: I need to see the output of svn status to give you a better answer. Perhaps the file has not really changed or it was somehow removed from version control.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening when there is a conflict between local file and the repository file. Try to synchronize the files (right click -> team -> synchronize). In this view you will see any conflicts you have.
In command line use `svn status` to check the status, this might say the skip reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the SVN is started with the same user as the repository has been created. When I restated my SVN I got the same error. Then realized that I have not start my SVN with the root user.